# Forecasting Year over Year Daily change in data in Excel

Tags: excel, forecasting

I have data that looks as shown below

[image: Trend Line Forecasting]
The blue line is for 2016 and the orange line is for 2017.

The X-Axis represents Days which are equivalent days between years. So for example day 20 might be 5/1/17 (for the 2017 year) and 5/2/16 (for the 2016 year).

The Y-Axis is the number of hours enrolled and each day it increases until around day 130 when the registration system closes.

I have historical data for 5 years but I want to make a forecast where the 2017 curve takes the same shape as the previous year's curve.

I have tried the Forecasting tool in Excel 2016 in two ways:
1. Forecast just on the 2017 data - not correct because it has no way to take the shape of historical data into account.
2. I lined up 2016 and 2017 in the same column then did the forecast but it was still completely wrong.

I tried also charting the curves and using linear, logistic, polynomial but none of thse approximate my actual curve.

Comment: You could look at something like K=E130/E80 or Q=E130/AVG(E70:E80) where E### is the enrollment on day ###. If K or Q is consistent from year to year through 2016 then you might be able to use an average value for K or Q to forecast 2017 enrollment.